# XAML TextBox: How to keep height fixed even though verticalalignment stretched?

Tags: xaml, textbox, height

I implemented a custom control which simply contains a label and a textbox to enter multiline text:

```
<DockPanel Name="MyStackPanel" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" LastChildFill="True" >
    <Label DockPanel.Dock="Top"  Content="{Binding MyTitle}" Style="{StaticResource PropertyNameLabelStyle}" />
    <TextBox DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Text="{Binding Path=MyText, Mode=TwoWay}" IsReadOnly="{Binding MyIsReadOnly}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" AcceptsReturn="True" Margin="5,5,5,5" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" IsUndoEnabled="True"  />
</DockPanel>
```

It is important that the `TextBox` fills all the space its parent has to offer but not more - which is working well with the code above. However if the user types more text than the displayed `TextBox` offers the `TextBox` rather becomes bigger (higher) then simply enabling the vertical `ScrollBar`, which is what I - and I guess most of all other programmers - want.

Comment: WPF! Are there differences?

Answer (score 0):

I am very new to XAML but I thought you might like to try this:

I set the `VerticalAlignment` for the TextBox itself:

```
<TextBox Text="ABC" MinWidth="200" VerticalAlignment="Center">
</TextBox>
```

It worked for me.